# How to get all headers data from angular http request

Tags: angular

I m using angular 13. when I send a request from Post Man I get all header information. (image 1)

[image: image 1]

Browser also is giving the whole header information (image 2)
[image: image 1]

Here is my code

```
return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + "user/getAllUsers", {observe:'response',params}).pipe(
  map(response => {       
    const paginationHeader = response.headers.get('pagination')

    console.log(response)

    return response;
  })
)
```

}

But. after sending the request from angular. It just provide me only one data from header
which is content type. (image 3)

[image: image 3]

I want all header information from request to show in the console. I will be really grateful if anyone help me regarding this problem

Comment: Have you tried with interceptor ?

Comment: no.. why should I try with interceptor ?. it's just a simple API request that I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in your backend API response.

Please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)